# Transparent Help Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

I'm developing a Android App, and I would like to implement a help like this:

http://developer.android.com/design/media/help_cling.png

How i can do this? It's beautiful and I think is very usefull.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this:

```
<activity android:name=".usual.activity.Declaration"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

This should help you.

Comment: It also can help me. When I finish my "Help Activity" I post it here, but I have and another question, I can start a Activity above another Activity?

Thank You @lopez.mikhael

Comment: Only your imagination can stop you, you can chain the number of "Transparent Help" you want!!

Comment: You have a lot of reason. I will try to do this, I'm not at Android Expert, but i think this gonna work well. Thank You @lopez.mikhael!

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ShowcaseView`](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/showcase-view/), as seen on AndroidViews.net:

[image]

Comment: Ohhh! It's perfect, this user library is editable? I mean, is modificable? I'm not sure, is very similar at Android default theme. Thank You! @CommonsWare

Comment: @Hypnotize: "this user library is editable? I mean, is modificable?" -- it is open source AFAIK.